# Click event of externally loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf with a full size button with following code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

buttonName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnFx);

function btnFx(e:MouseEvent){
    buttonName.alpha = 0;
}
```

When I load this SWF into another SWF's blank movieclip,  the above function of externally loaded SWF does not work. Is there a way to make the click reach to externally loaded SWF?

Comment: Try : `mc.mouseChildren = true;` ... it's just a guess. Try to show more details about your app.

Comment: should work, something else is going on. What's buttonName?

Comment: It works well independently. Actually the external SWF is being loaded in 3rd level child.

Comment: @Gaurav Normally level doesn't matter. Verify that `mouseChildren` is enabled and that your loaded SWF and its parent are accessible for the mouse click ...